# Which file is loaded after the index.php?

Tags: php, html, smarty, prestashop

I need some help. I have a index.php file from a template that contains only this:

```
<?php
/*
* 2007-2012 PrestaShop
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
* needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
*
*  @author PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
*  @copyright  2007-2012 PrestaShop SA
*  @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
*  International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
*/

header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

header("Location: ../");
exit;
?>
```

I just would like to know, which file is loaded after the index.php file. I can't figure it out from what the index.php file says.

It's this site. And I ultimately want to change the "Panier" in to another name for it. Thus I need to locate the file which contains the source of this string.

Comment: The file loaded after this file is probably `../index.php`

Comment: all this file does is redirect you down a level

Comment: after this `/themes/your theme name OR default/header.tpl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mike and @Dagon have noted in the comments, all this script is doing is redirecting you down one level. This will load the default file if that level is still in the public web root directory - either index.html, index.php, or whatever the default file is set to be.

Answer (score 1):

This file is here to avoid to list the folder themes/prestashop/

It s commom sens on all CMS, by example under Joomla it s an empty file named index.html